# After impersonating a domain user on windows, an app running as administrator cannot load the profile

Tags: impersonation, user-profile

I'm trying to load the user profile (using `LoadUserProfile` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but the API fails when the user is a windows domain user.

The application runs with an Administrative user (not System Account, the same code in a service running as System Account works).

The same code works if the user I want to access is a local user.

Is there any limitation for the LoadUserProfile and Windows Domain User? LoadUserProfile returns Access denied. Are there any policies which limit the API?

My code does the following:

1. LogonUser
2. LoadUserProfile - This fails with access denied.
3. ImpersonateLoggedOnUser

I'm not sure if the issue is 100% related with my code, because if I run

runas /user:domain\user cmd.exe
I got the same failure:
"Access denied"

So it seems that there are policies which control the behavior of Domain users.